# Show $Spec(A\otimes_R \kappa)\to Spec(A)$ is injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $p$ be a prime ideal in the commutative ting $R$ and set $\kappa:=Frac(R/p)$. Let $R\to \kappa$ be the induced homomorphism and let $R\to A$ be a ring homomorphism.
Show that $Spec(A\otimes_R \kappa)\to Spec(A)$ is injective.

I think I saw a post showing bijectivity but without showing surjectivity and injectivity and the argument was beyond me. Is there a simple way to just show injectivity?

Comment: Maybe writing $A\otimes_R \kappa=(R/\mathfrak{p})^{-1}(A/\mathfrak{p}A)$ helps